# Logging to file on deployed server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to debug an issue on my deployed phoenix app. Is there a simple way to enable file logging?

Similar to how rails creates uat.log and production.log

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed this by using this library:

https://github.com/onkel-dirtus/logger_file_backend

I added it to my mix.exs

```
{:logger_file_backend, "0.0.4"}
```

And then added this to my environment config (dev.exs and prod.exs):

```
config :logger, format: "[$level] $message\n",
  backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}, :console]

config :logger, :error_log,
  path: "log/error.log",
  level: :error
```

More information can be found in [the Logger docs](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html).